# What is the difference between homework-like questions/check-my-work questions and a normal question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons, homework-and-exercises

Yesterday, while I was trying to solve a [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) with a specific type, I came across with this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170546/).

Then I thought that *if* I ask a similar question for a different potential and add my work to make readers grasp what I am trying to solve, it should be fine. Then I asked [my question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/783616/). Then it was closed, which I was OK with.

However, I do try to understand the reason mine is closed while the question I linked to is not closed. Before asking this, I read a few other meta posts, [1](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9826/), [2](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/), and so on.

Moderators usually remove it if it focuses on "**Am I right?**" or lack of "**asking about a specific physics concept**", which I believe is not the case for my question.

**Update**
It seems my question is reopened.

Comment: You've posted a PDE and said, "I got to HERE when solving it, how do I finish?" which is the same thing as the common HW question that gets closed.

Comment: Then the only problem is "I got to HERE"? Would it be okey I hadn't shared my work in question?

Comment: [*It's not enough to just show your work and ask where you went wrong. If you just need someone to check your work, you can always seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher*](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/25301)

Comment: And if you do want that kind of help, see [this FAQ](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/25301)